# Why do lead-acid batteries fail after about five years of operation?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I had some time ago a failure in the batteries of my UPS. The UPS periodically performs a self-test of the battery, and it failed, causing all the computers behind the UPS to shut down. The batteries were gel cells, and failed five years after I purchased them.

What is the physical/chemical reason for the batteries failing after about five years of operation? I do understand that lead-acid batteries suffer from sulfation if not kept continuously full, but in this application they were continuously full and in fact never saw a full discharge cycle.

I have adjusted the float charging voltage to be 13.65 V. Is the float charging voltage incorrect, as the batteries failed? According to Wikipedia, starting batteries suffer early damage if kept in continuous charge due to corrosion, but these are not starting batteries.

Comment: "maintenance-free" = unmaintainable

Comment: http://www.power-thru.com/documents/The%20Truth%20About%20Batteries%20-%20POWERTHRU%20White%20Paper.pdf  It sounds like you got the expected 5 year life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring specific gravity and electrolyte levels can lead to longer life with periodic full equalization charging.  Pulse charging can also reduce sulphation rate but not replace need to periodically equalize cells with full charge voltage. ( e.g. every 6 mos)  Ambient temperature rise greatly accelerates sulphation.

https://googlegalaxychemistry.blogspot.ca/2017/03/leadacid-battery-preventive-maintenance.html#content

http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/archive/can_the_lead_acid_battery_compete_in_modern_times

Answer (score 1):

Five years is not that bad for a non-AGM battery

Float charge voltage for lead acid batteries is about 2.26v per cell plus or minus 0.1v

NEVER over charge a sealed battery. Set the float at 2.25v/cell.

Temperature should be kept near 20°C ambient.

While charging the charge the internal temperature should be held at 25°C or charge voltage should be reduced by 3mV per cell for each degree above and increased by 3mV per cell for each degree below.

The charge voltage ripple should be limited  to 5%.

And you have no deep discharge issues or water and electrolyte to maintain.

Lead Acid batteries use a CC/CV (constant current/voltage) charge method.

Lead Acid needs a slow charge, 12-18 hrs, in two stages, CC and CV.  A stationary battery even a slower charge is beneficial, around 3x slower.

For your stationary sealed battery, 36-48 hours.

The first stage, is a constant current which lasts for about 3-4 hours until the battery is about 70% charged.

Stage two is a "topping charge" a constant voltage, as the battery starts to saturate the current gradually slows.  When the charge reaches 3–5% of the its rated capacity, stage two is over.  This usually takes about 7–10 hrs (20-30 hrs for yours).

The battery should not stay at the topping voltage for more than 48 hrs.  This is critical for sealed batteries. Sealed batteries are not overcharge tolerant.

Setting the correct full charge voltage (2.30 - 2.35v per cell) is critical and debatable. Keeping the battery at topping voltage, this maximum capacity avoids sulfation on the negative plate.  On the the hand over charge saturation causes grid corrosion on the positive plate.  It's a balancing act.

For a stationary battery under load, after stage two, the battery would then go into a float charge at about 2.26v/cell.

For a UPS, not being under load,  rather than a float charge a hysteresis charge is recommended.  When the battery goes to standby after the full charge, the float disconnects.  When the voltage drops due to self-discharge a CV topping-charge is used to bring it back to full charge.

Pulse charging should not be used.  Sulfation can not be measured so pulse charging results are inconclusive.  Why fix what may not be broke, at the risk of doing harm?  The topping charge does a good job at preventing sulfation.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do to extend the life of sealed / gel batteries. With wet batteries you have options. I had a car battery last 11 years by adding EDTA and also doing an equalizing charge a few times a year: 4 amp solar panel connected for a few hours, lots of bubbling.

Golf Cart batteries lasted years also, with EDTA and they were connected to the solar panel through a charge controller. But I had some problems with the controller at first (long wires to panel made it oscillate) so the golf cart batteries overcharged sometimes (smelled like a swamp in the radio room).

If you want to make a small solar - battery system for emergencies or hobby, a modest panel and two golf cart batteries with EDTA added is your cheapest and best bet.